# How to zoom in page for retina device

Tags: jquery, retina

I have create app by cordova, everything work.
Now I put the app's html in website, page look too small in retian device,
How can I zoom in all the page for retina device.

I have try

```
if(window.devicePixelRatio == 2){
  document.body.style.zoom="200%"
}
```

But result not good,  some element zoom in 2x,  some element don't.

My question is :  Is there way to zoom in whole page in retina device's browser?

Comment: I resolved by add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2">